# text mining en R, función dtm

Tags: r

Buenos días, 
soy nuevo en la comunidad y tengo un problema con un código que me esta volviendo loco, es el siguiente:

Estoy trabajando con un corpus formado por 52 documentos al que aplico una serie de funciones de limpieza a través de la librería tm. El problema se produce con los acentos, los limpio correctamente con la función chartr (una solución que encontré en este foro) y finalmente obtengo mi corpus final bien limpio. Sin embargo, cuando creo un dtm estas mismas palabras que aparentemente ya no tiene acento, vuelven a aparecer mal con este símbolo Ã. Adjunto el codigo:

```
docs = Corpus(DirSource(camino), readerControl = list(language = "spa"))
# MUY IMPORTANTE, PARA QUE  INTRA-DIA NO SE CONVIERTA EN INTRADIA, ESTO ES, 
PARA QUE SUSTITUYA LOS SIMBOLOS DE PUNTUACION QUE QUITA POR ESPACIOS EN 
BLANCO.
corpus_clean <- tm_map(docs, removePunctuation, preserve_intra_word_dashes = 
TRUE)
corpus_clean <- tm_map(corpus_clean, content_transformer(tolower))
corpus_clean = tm_map(corpus_clean,removeWords,stopwords("Spanish"))
corpus_clean <- tm_map(corpus_clean, content_transformer(stripWhitespace))
# Aquí quitamos acentos y ñ:
removeAccents <- content_transformer(function(x) chartr("áéíóúñ", "aeioun", 
x))
corpus_clean <- tm_map(corpus_clean, removeAccents)
dtm = DocumentTermMatrix(corpus_clean) #problema comentado al visualizar el 
dtm
```

Muchas gracias,
Un saludo.

Comment: Puedes escibir los resultados del ordern `sessionInfo()`?

Answer (score 0):

Hace algún tiempo tuve el mismo problema, pero termine por borrar las letras acentuadas por que tampoco me importaba mucho, supongo que para ti no es la solución. En este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610319/convert-accented-characters-into-ascii-character) hay algunas soluciones. De todas ellas podrías intentar esta:

```
library(stringi)
stri_trans_general("Zażółć gęślą jaźń", "Latin-ASCII")
```

Debería funcionar. De todas formas no estaría mal que pusieran Info de la Session.

Espero que ayude y bienvenido!